# Как проверить input(), равняется ли он элементам списка?

Tags: python, функции, list

Собственно, пытаюсь написать мини-переводчик на Python, по приколу, и столкнулся с проблемкой. Я в питоне далеко не ас и не могу понять, как проверить input(), равняется ли он хотя бы одному элементу базы слов. Помогите пожалуйста.
Вот кусочек кода с базой и инпутом, нужно дописать уже описанным образом check():

```
base_eng = ['Hi', 'Hello', 'Apple']
base_rus = ['Привет', 'Здравствуй', 'Яблоко']
word_rus = (str(input("Введите слово: ")))
def check():
```

UPD: Т.к. база маленькая, я бы мог сделать отдельные проверки на каждое слово, но это длинно и я собираюсь сделать базу больше.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для проверки наличия в базе можно так:

```py
base_eng = ['Hi', 'Hello', 'Apple']
base_rus = ['Привет', 'Здравствуй', 'Яблоко']
word_rus = (str(input("Введите слово: ")))

def check(bs_ru, bs_en, word):
    if word in bs_ru: 
        print("Есть в base_rus")
    elif word in bs_en:
        print("Есть в base_en")
    else:
        print("Нет")

check(base_rus, base_eng, word_rus)
```

Только если хотите перевод то Надо либо подставлять аналогичные слова по индексу, или записать все данные в словари.

Немного странного кода но c функцией переводчика:

```py
base_eng = ['Hi', 'Hello', 'Apple']
base_rus = ['Привет', 'Здравствуй', 'Яблоко']
word_rus = (str(input("Введите слово: ")))

def check(bs_ru, bs_en, word):
    if word in bs_ru:
        # При условии что индексы слов в base_eng и base_rus совпадают. 
        print(f"{word} переводится как {bs_en[bs_ru.index(word)]}")
    else:
        print("Нет")

check(base_rus, base_eng, word_rus)
```

Comment: Замечательно! Обязательно сделаю так!

Answer (score 0):

Я до конца вопрос не понял но возможно это то что тебе нужно:

```
def check():
    if word_rus == "Hi":
        print("Привет")
    elif word_rus == "Hello":
        print("Здраствуйте")
    elif word_rus == "Apple":
        print("Яблоко")

check()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
translate = input("что перевести?")
translate = translate.split()
FILENAME = "trn.txt"
f = open(FILENAME, "r")
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    line = line.split(";")
    for word in translate:
        if word == line[0]:
            print(line[1])
f.close()
```

Нужно будет создать файл "trn" и написать там слово, а потом через ";" перевод.

Каждое слово и перевод на отдельной строке (можно написать много слов).
Когда запустите программу, то увидите сообщение "что перевести?". Напишите слово (если его не будет в файле, то перевода не будет) и увидите перевод.

Знаю, что это не оптимальный вариант, но в нем не надо писать какие-то списки прямо в коде, а это сокращает его.